# Why Getting categories and names on product view page Magento 2 fails?

Tags: magento2, category, layout, magento-2.1, template

I am using the `getCategories()` function below:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;

class Categories extends AbstractProduct
{

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(Context $context,
                                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                                array $data = [])
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $cats = $product->getCategoryCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect("name")
            ->addIsActiveFilter();
        return $cats;
    }
}
```

The layout file `catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Company\ProductCategories\Block\Product\View\Categories"
                   name="product.view.categories"
                   template="Company_ProductCategories::product/view/categories.phtml"
                   before="product.social.links">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And the template file `categories.phtml`:

```
<?php
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categories */
    $categories = $this->getCategories();
?>

<?php if ($categories->getSize() > 0): ?>
<div id="product.view.categories">
    <p>Categories:
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So this returns the category names when going to a product from a category page.

However when I go to a product view from the front page through a new or latest products block, it does not add the category names to the results.
It also doesn't add the proper path of breadcrumbs.

Just a bit more info the url when navigating from the catalog page:

`http://shop.dev/ammunition/airgun/exact-airgun-pellets-44gr-500.html`

Where `ammunition` and `airgun` are the categories.

when going from the home page the url is just:

`http://shop.dev/exact-airgun-pellets-44gr-500.html`

I tested this on a standard magento install and whether going to the page from a catalog page or the home page the url is the same: `http://magento2.dev/index.php/hero-hoodie.html` and the categories show.

**Why is that on this porto theme, there is an issue?**

Comment: Which block class you use?

Comment: I am using a custom module block that extends `abstractProduct`

Comment: Can you give more detail with code?

Comment: @SohelRana I have updated the code. Please take a look.

Comment: Can you show your layout xml file?

Comment: @SohelRana It has been updated

Comment: All good here .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52053/discussion-between-stevie-g-and-sohel-rana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm, **I've tested your code on a fresh Magento 2.1.2 and it works absolutely fine in both cases (when accessing the product via its direct URL or when accessing the product via the category).**

Regarding your second question: yes I'm 90% sure the Porto theme is the problem. **All those themes are shipped with a huge number of widgets, modules, custom modifications which are very often the root cause of many issues.**

I'm not saying those themes are bad, **they're great when you're dealing with a small store which do not need a lot of custom development and modifications.** However, when you're dealing with a bigger structure, problems arise.

Comment: What is strange is that I can get the category url with `->getUrl()`...